# Why does "File's Owner" sometimes have a "view" outlet? Can I add my own?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib, iboutlet, nsviewcontroller

When I create a new "Cocoa Class", of type NSViewController, and check "Also create XIB file for user interface", I get a blank xib file.  Its "File's Owner" has an outlet "view" which is connected to the custom view.

When I create a new "View" (xib file), its "File's Owner" doesn't have a "view" outlet, or any other kind.  There's a just a "New Referencing Outlet", and I can't connect it to the view.

Why does one kind of xib have a "view" here, and the other doesn't?  Is there a way to add a "view" outlet to "File's Owner" on my own xib?

There must be something special about the xib created by "Also create XIB file for user interface", but I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made xibs both ways, and diff'd them.  For a xib created through that checkbox, its "File's Owner" has a Custom Class which is the name of an NSViewController.  That's what gives it the "view" outlet.

You can set the Class of the File's Owner on any xib to an NSViewController, and then it will get a "view" outlet for you to set.